# jQuery smooth scroll not working properly in ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, smooth-scrolling

i tried 2 scripts to scroll to specific element.It works fine in android,Pc.But when i try it in ipad it jumps and not smooth.

here are these script i have tried on click event of anchor tags

```
   var id = jQuery(this).attr("href");
   var offset = 60;
   var target = jQuery(id).offset().top - offset;
```

**Script1**

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 1200);
```

**Script2**

```
  jQuery("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollLeft: jQuery(target).offset().left,
      scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top - 100
    }, 900,'easeInSine');
```

Comment: I've never used, but have seen many people recommend [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) when it comes to smooth scrolling and I-devices. May be worth a shot.

Comment: Try css3 animations, they are hardware accelerated animations and will work smoother.

Answer (score 0):

i switched to jquery scroll to plugin with method and it works fine

```
jQuery(id).ScrollTo({
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear',
     'axis':'y'
});
```